# how to utilize MainSkin.xaml in MVVM Light?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I currently define some static resources and a style that uses those resources in my window.  I would like to move that markup over to the MainSkin.xaml, and then be able to reference it in all windows in which I need that style.

If I simply move the markup over I get a "Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension'" exception.  I'm assuming that it cannot find the style I'm referencing?  Do I need to merge it/link it somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WPF and Silverlight, you can create any number of resource dictionaries you need. This is purely a logical organization of resources. There is no difference between resources added into an external resource dictionary and then merged into, for instance, `Page.Resources`, and resources added directly into `Page.Resources`.

In practice, we typically define a number of resource dictionaries:

- Global resource dictionaries: These are merged into `App.xaml`, which makes them automatically available to all pages/windows/user controls in the application.
- Specific resource dictionaries, which contain resources that are specific to a given Window, Page/User control.

`MainSkin.xaml` is supposed to be specific to `MainWindow` (as the name shows). This is a suggestion only, and you are free to do as you want ;) however in your case, if you have resources that are used in multiple places, I would rather create a global resource dictionary, merge it into `App.xaml` and add them there.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I guess being a noob with mvvm I drew a parallel to have a Styles.css that is applied to all pages.  I guess I can achieve that as you suggested by merging something like a GlobalSkin.xaml in App.xaml.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question as I figured it out.  Every page that uses MainSkin.xaml needs to merge it into its resources.  By default MainWindow created by MVVM Light will have that done for you, but additional windows you need to carry the merging markup over.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <! -- OTHER RESOURCES GO HERE, NOT DIRECTLY UNDER WINDOW.RESOURCES!!! -->

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```